# Coding bat( Python > List-1 > same_first_last

Tags: python

The function is given a list and must return True if the 1st and last digit of the list are same.

```
def same_first_last(nums):
   if nums[0] == nums[len(nums) - 1]:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

The function returns " index value out of range". Please help

Comment: Is the list empty?

Comment: nums[-1] should do it unless the list is empty like Willem said.

Comment: @YOBA: but it is equivalent to `nums[len(nums)-1]`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No.. input list be like [1,2,3,1] or [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue without an empty list. How do you call the function?

Comment: @YOBA exactly what william has said. Both are equivalent, but one works and the other doesn't. Why?

Comment: @RajatChauhan: but these examples succeed...

Comment: @RajatChauhan: please provide an example that errors. I've tried your function and it works.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i m writing that in coding bat and it's not working. saying list index out of range

Comment: This sounds like an issue with coding bat then? I cannot find a test case in which `nums[-1]` works and `nums[len(nums)-1]` doesn't, which you've stated in an earlier comment.

Comment: `return nums[0] == nums[-1] if nums else False`. Note that `if nums else False` handles the case when nums is empty.  `nums[-1]` references the same location as `nums[len(nums) - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what to do with the case where you give an **empty list**. It depends on how you see it: if you see an empty list as a number with no digits, you  can argue that the first and last digit are the same. In that case you can write:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    return not nums or nums[0] == nums[-1]
```

If you consider an empty list **not** to have the same first and last digit, you can use:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    return bool(nums) and nums[0] == nums[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify:

```
 if nums[0] == nums[-1]:
       return True

 return False
```

but I think the error " index value out of range" ,may the **nums** post in this function may empty list

Comment: Why do you use `if` to return `True/False`?

Comment: `return nums[0] == nums[-1]` is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the list is empty or not. Assuming the list is not empty. The method looks like as below.

```
  def same_first_last(nums)
      return True if a[0]==a[-1] else False
```

nums[-1] is the shortcut to get the last element from a list. The nums[-n] syntax gets the nth-to-last element. Example:

```
 nums = [1,2,3,1,3]
 nums[-2] #returns 1
 nums[-3] #returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def same_first_last(nums):
   return ((not nums or nums[0] == nums[-1]) and len(nums) >= 1)
```

it's work good as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).